# HTML DIVs not properly displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have what I think is a reasonably simple HTML format to display some financial information. For some reason, jQuery (and, indeed, Firebug!) don't seem to update the visual display of the parent divs. This is a lot easier to see if you look at this in a browser.

I'm using the [Bluetrip CSS](http://bluetrip.org/) framework.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<!--[if IE]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link href="jquery.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#txn-41').css("background-color", 'yellow')
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main span-19">
  <div class="span-19 push-1">
    <h2>Recently added</h2>

    <div id="transaction-list">
      <div id="transactions">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="cell span-3">
            date
          </div>

          <div class="cell span-3">
            w/d
          </div>

          <div class="cell span-3">
            deposit
          </div>

          <div class="cell span-3">
            category
          </div>

          <div class="cell span-3">
            user
          </div>

          <div class="cell span-3">
            account
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="txn-41">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $2,233.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Entertainment
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Checking
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-41" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>

        <div id="txn-40">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $5,555.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Groceries
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Checking
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-40" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>

        <div id="txn-39">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $5,555.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Groceries
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Checking
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-39" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>

        <div id="txn-38">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $123.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Groceries
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Checking
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-38" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>

        <div id="txn-37">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $223.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Entertainment
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Savings
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-37" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>

        <div id="txn-36">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $998.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Entertainment
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Savings
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-36" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>

        <div id="txn-34">
          <div class="cell date" title="Monday September 21, 2009">
            2009-09-29
          </div>

          <div class="cell wd">
            $20.00
          </div>

          <div class="cell deposit">
            &nbsp;
          </div>

          <div class="cell category">
            Groceries
          </div>

          <div class="cell user">
            Tim
          </div>

          <div class="cell account">
            Checking
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="edit-txn-34" style="display: none; clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar span-5 last"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    /* @override http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/dough.css */

    body {
        background-color: #E5E5E5;
    }

    .main, .sidebar {
        background-color: white;
        padding-top: 8px;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

    .txn {
        clear: both;
    }

    .cell {
        float:left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .cell.date {
        width: 110px;
    }

    .cell.wd {
        width: 110px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .cell.deposit {
        width: 110px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .cell.category {
        width: 110px;
    }

    .cell.user {
        width: 110px;
    }

    .cell.account {
        width: 110px;
    }
```

If you look at this in Firebug (or Safari's inspect element), you'll see that the jQuery call is, in fact, changing the style of the #txn-41 div, but it's not changing in the browser.

Why isn't the #txn-41 div visible? The contents of it are visible, but I can't seem to apply effects to the parent!

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be because all of its children divs are floated. Floating elements don't contribute to the height of their container (except in IE, I believe), so in your case, your `#txn-41` div probably has a height of 0.

If you add a "clearing" div as the last child that should solve it (if this is in fact the problem):

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

There are also CSS methods which can do this automatically for you by adding content which clears the floats.

[Here's a good article explaining the problem](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) which also shows the CSS method for fixing it (no extra markup required). In short, add this to your `#txn-41` div:

```
#txn-41:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

(or make it a class)

---

I just read in [this Sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/) about several other methods for solving the problem, including the bizarrely simple method of merely declaring the outer containing div as having `overflow: auto`. Somehow, that works.

```
#txn-41 { overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: Mighty, thanks! The :after did it, though the overflow did not.